# Slider com seta de avanço específica

Tags: slider

Eu preciso de um slider que tenha por padrão uma seta de avanço e retorno de slides igual a essa da imagem, nesse formato, e grande assim. Eu geralmente uso o Slick-carousel e o Owl-carousel, mas as setas deles são diferentes.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recomendo https://flickity.metafizzy.co/ sua api permite manipular o estilo desses botões https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#arrowshape

Comment: Eu uso o WOWSlider. É fácil de configurar e possui vários templates com setas e estilos diferentes: http://wowslider.com/pt-br/